# Keep @ character unescaped

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have the following route:

```
get "/@:user_name", UserController, :show
```

Which appears to work. However, when I use the URL helper:

```
user_path( @conn, :show, @current_user.user_name )
```

The output is fully escaped:

> https://url.com/%40user

If I implement the route like this:

```
get "/@/:user_name", UserController, :show
```

Then the @ symbol is outputted un-escaped:

> https://url.com/@/user

Is there a way to implement the first route without escaping for the @ symbol? Is using the @ symbol in the URL path a bad idea?

Comment: Have you tried using just `/:username` and pattern matching on the string? Maybe something like this in your controller: `def show(conn, %{"params" => "@" <> username})` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the phoenix helper [expands segments and then encodes params](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/cb469a4d2f7ee3ca14b1a4bf8de4ee7a590067a5/lib/phoenix/router/helpers.ex#L305). The last segment in `http://url.com/@user` is considered being a param, while in `http://url.com/@/user` it is not.

There might be different opinions on is it the correct way, or not, but the truth is that your param (user name in this particular case) is typically coming from the outside world, while the route itself comes from your code. That’s why `http://url.com/@/user` is not `URI.encode`d.

I would not fight against how phoenix handles it and simply would go with `http://url.com/@/user` or like.

*OTOH, `https://url.com/%40user` and `https://url.com/@user` are exactly the same from the point of view of your browser and lead to the same destination.*

Hope it helps.

Comment: It helps confirm what I thought was going on. I mainly wanted the @ symbol (instead of %40) so that it looks aesthetically pleasing and so the user knows they can use the same format to look at another users profile

Comment: I was thinking that I might do a little post-processing on the user_path call and replace the %40 with an @ symbol if it was in the root of the URL path. Assuming that this doesn't break any rules with the @ symbol in the url path

Comment: In my opinion, you are safe to post-process it, yes.